# unable to get parent reference in sencha touch when calling function is in html attribute

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, sencha-touch

I need to make a general method in the controller of sencha touch so that other similar modules in the application can fetch those piece of codes. But now I'm stuck as I'm nowhere getting its solution (even after tried 100 times on Google). The thing is that the calling function is in the 'html' attribute, and now we need its parent reference so that all other its siblings can be referenced, take a look on the code below:

```
<Ext.form.IFieldSet>{   //  THIS SHOWS ONLY if there is existing data under "other income"
                    xtype: 'fieldset',
                    title: 'Other Income',
                    itemId: 'OtherIncomeFirstSet',
                    //instructions: '<hr class="separate" />',
                    items: [
                        <Ext.field.ISelect>{
                            xtype: 'selectfield',
                            name: 'BorrowerPositionFirstSet',
                            label: 'Borrower Position',
                            store: 'BorrowerPositionSelectorStore',
                            //usePicker: false,
                            disabled: true,
                        },
                        <Ext.field.ISelect> {
                            xtype: 'selectfield',
                            name: 'IncomeTypeFirstSet',
                            label: 'Income Type',
                            store: 'IncomeTypeSelectorStore',
                            //usePicker: false,
                            disabled: true,
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'textfield',
                            name: 'DescriptionFirstSet',
                            label: 'Description',
                            disabled: true,
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'numberfield',
                            name: 'MonthlyAmountFirstSet',
                            label: 'Monthly Amount',
                            disabled: true,
                        },
                        <Ext.form.IField>{
                            xtype: 'field',
                            label: ' ',
                            //this is the html attribute I am talking about...
                            html: '<a href="#" onclick="event.preventDefault();App.app.getController(\'lead.leadsListController\').onClickDelete(this)" class="ta-textlink deleteLink">Delete</a><a href="#" onclick="event.preventDefault();App.app.getController(\'lead.leadsListController\').onClickEdit(this)" class="ta-textlink editLink">Edit</a>'
                        }
                    ]
```

As you can see the calling functions are inside the html and I don't wan't to use 'parentNode'( which is pure javascript) as I had to do something like this:

```
var parentRef = (ref.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.....);
```

and you can see this is simply crap! Please sencha developers help me getting the solution for this. How can I get the reference **itemId: 'OtherIncomeFirstSet'** through its childs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use a button (or two) for this. Sounds like a bit CSS and the button will do the trick. Plus you could really use it inside your controller. Fieldset does not imply that you cannot use buttons.

Hint: try never ever to call upon a controller from the outside.

If you really have to go with field and a click event, use the following code (dont forget, this is not my preference, as this could be written nicely in ST with two buttons, really!!!!):

```
<Ext.form.IField>{
    xtype: 'field',
    label: ' ',
    //this is the html attribute I am talking about...
    html: '<a href="#" onclick="event.preventDefault(); ' +
        'Ext.Viewport.down('.form').fireEvent('delete') ' + // <<<< Here fire the event
        'class="ta-textlink deleteLink">' +
            'Delete' +
        '</a>' +
        '<a href="#" onclick="event.preventDefault(); ' +
        'Ext.Viewport.down('.form').fireEvent('edit') ' +  // <<<<< And here
        'class="ta-textlink editLink">' +
            'Edit' +
        '</a>'
}
```

and inside the controller

```
config: {
    refs: {
        myView: '.myView', //Whatever the basic view is you created
        form: '.myview .form'
    },
    control: {
        form: {
            delete: 'onDelete',  // <<<< here you listen to the event
            edit: 'onEdit'
        }
    }
},

onDelete: function() {},
onEdit: function() {}
```

Comment: Worked your way and I know it will work as I had used buttons before....well anyways, thanks for answering.

Comment: Just answered this question, which might be the better solution for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26468423/sencha-touch-list-tpl-event-reference