# sencha touch list tpl event reference

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

In my list view, I put `addEventListener`( alias `on`) in my `initialize` event

```
initialize: function (component) {
        component.element.on({
            tap: {
                scope: this,
                fn: 'onTap',
                delegate: 'div.side-itemDelete'
            }
        });
    },
```

But if there are more `delegate`( other element with id or class) I need to bind an event, how can I handle it?
This is my XTemplate:

```
new Ext.XTemplate(
    '<div class="side-weatherListItem no-dragging">',
        '<div class="side-itemLocation">',
            '<div>{[values.city.toUpperCase()]}</div>',
            '<div>{[values.text.toUpperCase()]}</div>',
        '</div>',
        '<div class="side-itemTemperature">{temp}°{unit}</div>',
        '<div class="side-itemState">',
            '<div><img src="./resources/img/rain.svg"></div>',
            '<div class="side-itemDate">11:38</div>',
        '</div>',
        '<div class="side-itemDelete" fire="onDelete">', // <<---- here
            '<img src="./resources/img/delete.svg">',
        '</div>',
    '</div>'
),
```

Comment: What events are you trying to bind? Also to display this are you using a list?

Comment: @Darly yes, I'm using a list. For instance, now I have bind an event to `side-itemDelete` by `delegate: 'div.side-itemDelete'`, if I want to bind an event on `div.side-itemTemperature` or more other element with tap event, how can I do?

Comment: @Proto Bassi beat me to the answer. The listener accepts multiple events(takes in an array of events to be accurate). Every Time a new item is made all the events are binded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify several listeners:

```
{
    xtype: 'list',
    listeners: [
        {
            event: 'tap',
            fn: function(){
                console.log('delete');
            },
            element: 'innerElement',
            delegate: '.side-itemDelete'
        },
        {
            event: 'tap',
            fn: function(){
                console.log('locate');
            },
            element: 'innerElement',
            delegate: '.side-itemLocation'
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: And what's the difference of `element:"innerElement"` and `element:"element"`? I see some examples don't use this field

Comment: Yes, it works. Either the element is `innerElement` or `element`

Comment: On delegation try to stay with innerElement whenever possible, otherwise go for element. Try to stay as close to the div you are looking for as possible, that will speed things up as much as possible.